# Mutex and Semaphore in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is the Synchronized keyword in java depend on a Mutex or a Semaphore ? I read that both these terms are used interchangeably, but there is a difference ? Are there any built in Semaphore classes in java ?

Comment: Mutex comes from mutual exclusion - the only thread accesses block of code, while semaphore allows several threads to execute a code. Sometimes it would be useful to allow several threads to enter code block. java.util.concurrent.Semaphore - semaphore, synchronized is closer to mutex.

Comment: `synchronized` is dependent on an object or a class, and it acts as a mutex. Are there any built in what...?

Comment: @user486075 It's from mutual exclusion.

Comment: I meant in JAVA SDK, is their any way to create a semaphore ?

Comment: There's a class and it's called... well, `Semaphore`.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between a `mutex` and a `semaphore` is that the `mutex` may be released only by the process/thread that holds it in contrast to the `semaphore` that may be released by any process/thread. There is also one more difference but not as significant: there is a kind of semaphore that is called counting semaphore, i.e. a semaphore that may be initialized to allow several concurrent 'holders'.

The `synchronized` access in Java semantically should be implemented using `mutex`.

Answer (score 0):

synchronized are implemented in term of [Thread Monitor](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch.html)

[java.util.concurrent.locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) is a package which contains some useful lock relative classes like [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

Answer (score 0):

Semaphore has a fixed number of permits which can be acquired/released while running a block of code. So a fixed number of threads equal to number of permits can run a code block at the same time. Mutex/Lock is a specialized version of the Semaphore where the number of permits is 1. That is only a single thread is allowed to run a certain code block. This gives the thread 'ownership' of the code block. Only the owner can acquire and release the lock on the code block.